# Группировка по одному полю

Tags: oracle

Допустим есть таблица из трёх столбцов, мне надо отобрать максимальное значение из третьего, сгруппировав только по первому!, а второй чтобы отображал значение, соответствующее максимальному значению в третьем. Как это сделать?

по логике в `GROUP BY` надо просто указать первый столбец не указывая второй (по моему так работает на `mysql`), но это приводит к ошибке.

Для примера запрос по логике должен выглядеть так

```
SELECT createby,num,MAX(dat)
FROM visit 
GROUP BY createby
```

соответственно `num` должен браться тот который соответствует `MAX(dat)` (максимальной дате)
Как составить верно такой запрос?

Comment: Покажите ваш пример, который приводит к ошибке(и кстати к какой)? Для обновления вопроса, нажмите кнопку "править"

Comment: В group by должны указываться поля, по которым идет группировка, а в select могут быть только поля из группировки или поля, участвующие в агрегировании данных, т.е. обернуты в функции sum, count и т.д.

Comment: это я понимаю, но как мне получить нужный мне результат, как должен выглядеть запрос? чтоб num в выборку попадал тот который соответствует MAX(dat)

Answer (score 0):

Можно данные вытащить вот таким запросом

```
WITH vis as (
    SELECT createby, MAX(dat)
    FROM visit 
    GROUP BY createby, 
)
select 
      v.createby
    , v.num
    , v.dat
from visit v, vis vw
where v.createby = vw.createby 
  and v.dat = vw.dat;
```

Answer (score 0):

> надо отобрать максимальное значение из третьего, сгруппировав только по первому!, а второй чтобы отображал значение, соответствующее максимальному значению в третьем.

Для этого в оракле есть функция keep

```
SELECT 
  createby,
  max(num) keep(dense_rank first order by dat desc nulls last),
  max(dat)
FROM visit 
GROUP BY createby
```